SSL receive failed. Read: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading: Success // Error while isntalling perforce server
I'm quite new with Ubuntu, I'm trying to install Perforce on a dedicated server, I'm using an OVHCloud server using Ubuntu Server 23.10 "Mantic Minotaur". I tried following multiple tutorials with different Ubuntu versions but always got the same error at one of the last steps. While performing the final configuration I get these error:
 error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading:
Does anyone know what may be causing this? I've been fighting this error for a couple of days and I'm quite frustrated

Try using 22.04 or 24.04, not 23.10 since support for that dies in less than a month.

It sounds a lot like the error mentioned here OpenSSL Error messages: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading except that Ubuntu 23.10 should already have curl version 8.2.x - but please check both curl --version and openssl version to confirm

I changed to Ubuntu 22.04 to avoid not having support as Thomas said but I'm still getting the same error. @steeldriver I have curl 7.88.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.88.1 OpenSSL/3.0.2 installed
